# jsplumb: set label on multiple overlays sets the label on all overlays to the same thing

Tags: jsplumb

In my bind:

```
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(e) { 
   jsPlumb.select(e).addOverlay(
       ["Label", {
       label: "my label",
       location: 0.5,
       cssClass: 'aLabel',
       id: uuid_line
       }]
);
```

I set that label to "my label".  If I draw another connection between the same source and target nodes, and do this:

```
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(e) { 
   jsPlumb.select(e).addOverlay(
       ["Label", {
       label: "my label2",
       location: 0.5,
       cssClass: 'aLabel',
       id: uuid_line2
       }]
);
```

Both labels on the overlay are set to "my label2".

I must be missing something obvious.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by changing:

```
jsPlumb.select(e).addOverlay(
```

to:

```
con.addOverlay(
```

where:

```
var con=e.connection;
```